# How to edit "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." text in Glype's browser.php?

Tags: php

When you install the Glype proxy server, the browser.php page contains a block of "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." text under the 'About' section. How to personalise that text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the "Lorem ipsum..." text, you need to edit the `themes\default\config.php` file - in particular, the `$themeReplace['description']` variable.